# IP address is not showing in a treeview

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, treeview

The IP address is not showing in Treeview.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<config>
  <service name="router">
    <ip_address>10.0.3.1</ip_address>
    <action>active</action>
  </service>
  <service name="sname2">
    <ip_address>10.0.3.2</ip_address>
    <weight>4</weight>
    <action>active</action>
  </service>
  <service name="sname3">
    <ip_address>10.0.3.3</ip_address>
    <weight>5</weight>
    <protocol>udp</protocol>
    <action>suspend</action>
  </service>
  <service name="nick">
    <ip_address>10.0.3.93</ip_address>
    <action>active</action>
  </service>
  <owner name="test">
    <content name="rule">
      <vip_address>10.0.3.100</vip_address>
      <protocol>udp</protocol>
      <port>8080</port>
      <add_service>nick</add_service>
      <action>active</action>
    </content>
  </owner>
</config>
```

In treeview, the IP address is not showing. I am loading from an XML file, so here is my code and screen. What is this issue?

[image]

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace howto_load_treeview_from_xml
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = Application.StartupPath;
            filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(filename, "..\\..");
            filename = Path.GetFullPath(filename) + "\\test.xml";
            LoadTreeViewFromXmlFile(filename, trvItems);
        }

        // Load a TreeView control from an XML file.
        private void LoadTreeViewFromXmlFile(string filename, TreeView trv)
        {
            // Load the XML document.
            XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
            xml_doc.Load(filename);

            // Add the root node's children to the TreeView.
            trv.Nodes.Clear();
            AddTreeViewChildNodes(trv.Nodes, xml_doc.DocumentElement);
        }

        // Add the children of this XML node
        // to this child nodes collection.
        private void AddTreeViewChildNodes(TreeNodeCollection parent_nodes, XmlNode xml_node)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode child_node in xml_node.ChildNodes)
            {
                // Make the new TreeView node.
                TreeNode new_node = parent_nodes.Add(child_node.Name);

                // Recursively make this node's descendants.
                AddTreeViewChildNodes(new_node.Nodes, child_node);

                // If this is a leaf node, make sure it's visible.
                if (new_node.Nodes.Count == 0) new_node.EnsureVisible();
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad Expanded the loading code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those bunch of `#text` get displayed in the treeview, because you're using `Name` property of text nodes as the treeview node name.

To get the actual value of the text nodes displayed, use `Value` property instead. Something like this (untested codes):

```
private void AddTreeViewChildNodes(TreeNodeCollection parent_nodes, XmlNode xml_node)
{
    foreach (XmlNode child_node in xml_node.ChildNodes)
    {
        var isTextNode = child_node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text;
        var treeNodeName = isTextNode ? child_node.Value : child_node.Name;
        
        // Make the new TreeView node.
        TreeNode new_node = parent_nodes.Add(treeNodeName);
        
        // Recursively make this node's descendants.
        AddTreeViewChildNodes(new_node.Nodes, child_node);
        
        // If this is a leaf node, make sure it's visible.
        if(new_node.Nodes.Count == 0) new_node.EnsureVisible();
    }
 }
```

Comment: var isTextNode = child_node == XmlNodeType.Text;  Is showing error

Comment: my bad, updated. Should've been `child_node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text` I think